# Ant pathconvert is not accepting newlines

Tags: ant

All I need is to create a file that contains a file names' list (separated by '\r\n' or '\n' depending on the OS) in a certain folder. For some reason, the code below doesn't work:

```
    <fileset id="my_files" dir="./resource">
        <include name="*.js" />
    </fileset>
    <pathconvert property="my_files_list" refid="my_files" pathsep="\r\n" />

    <echo message="${my_files_list}" file="my_files_list.txt"/>
```

I am getting the files' list, separate by a string that includes four characters '\r\n' literally. First, I would like them to convert into the real (whitespace) newline, second, I would like them to have an OS-dependent delimiter.

Please advice

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What *does* it do?

Comment: Just clarified. Thanks for pointing out. Does it help to understand better please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use the standard Ant `line.separator` property, rather than hard-coding it to `\r\n`.  This is also more likely to work, rather than being mangled by Ant, as seems to be happening here.

So try this:

```
<pathconvert property="my_files_list" refid="my_files" pathsep="${line.separator}" />
```