# Ant javac build not correctly taking classpath elements and compilation failure

Tags: java, ant

I have inherited a legacy project that used to build on Java 6 and now must be built on Java 8 in a DevOps scenario based on IBM Jazz RTC.

Formerly, the javac compiler was invoked with following classpath

```xml
    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.artifactory}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${common.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${wls.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${app.inf.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/> 
    <fileset dir="${web.inf.lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    <fileset dir="${myEar.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${weblogic.modules}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${weblogic.jar}"/>
    </path>
```

After upgrade of the build machines to Java 8, Ant complained that the command line was too long.

So, we were instructed to change the build file in order **not** not use `fileset` element, but `pathelement`. `build.xml` is as follows:

```xml
    <path id="build.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${common.lib.dir}/*"/>
        <pathelement location="${wls.lib.dir}/*"/>
        <pathelement location="${app.inf.lib.dir}/*"/>
        <pathelement location="${web.inf.lib.dir}/*"/> 
        <pathelement location="${myEar.dir}/*"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.artifactory}/*"/>
        <pathelement location="${weblogic.modules}/*"/>
        <pathelement location="${weblogic.jar}"/>
        <pathelement location="${wfm.jar}"/>
    </path>

  <target name="compile" depends="init">
    <javac target="${javacSourceTarget}" source="${javacSourceTarget}" debug="true" executable="${param.compilatore.executable}" fork="true" memoryMaximumSize="256m" srcdir="${srcWAR.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath">
      <include name="${maijava}" />
      <include name="${package}/**/*" />
      <include name="${package2}/**/*" />
      <include name="${package3}/**/*" />
      <include name="${package4}/**/*" />
      <include name="${package5}/**/*" />
      <exclude name="${packagejdo}" />
    </javac>
  </target>
```

(The `javac` task was not changed)

So, now the build fails because it can't find some JARs located under `${app.inf.lib.dir}`. For example, the following (redacted) occurs:

```
2022-09-05 13:11:29 [ExecTask         ]     [javac] Compiling 15 source files to /build/myEar_SRC/WORKAREA/elfi/classes  
2022-09-05 13:11:29 [ExecTask         ]     [javac] Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1  
2022-09-05 13:11:38 [ExecTask         ]     [javac] /build/myEar_SRC/SRC/elfi/war/src/com/acme/frontend/profilo/BeanProfilo.java:7: package com.acme.client does not exist  
2022-09-05 13:11:38 [ExecTask         ]     [javac] import com.acme.client.Response;  
2022-09-05 13:11:38 [ExecTask         ]     [javac]                                                ^  
2022-09-05 13:11:38 [ExecTask         ]     [javac] /build/myEar_SRC/SRC/elfi/war/src/com/acme/frontend/profilo/BeanProfilo.java:8: package com.acme.utils does not exist  
2022-09-05 13:11:38 [ExecTask         ]     [javac] import com.acme.utils.LogManager;
```

We have triple checked the SFTP directory pointed by `${app.inf.lib.dir}` and the jar is present.

I would like to understand why Ant is failing here and how can we import dozens of jars into the classpath without breaking the compilation process. I also can't display what jars are effectively included into the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pathconvert to log (echo) the path, see [Ant pathconvert is not accepting newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193262/ant-pathconvert-is-not-accepting-newlines)

If the path is too long for the command line you could try to create a file from the pathconvert result (prefixed with "-cp ") and use it as "@argfile" for javac, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCCFGCD

In Ant it should be possible to pass that "@argfile" using the compilerarg element of the javac task.